# Erlang :ssh authentication error. How to connect to ssh using identity file

Tags: erlang, elixir

I'm getting an authentication error when trying to connect ssh host.

The goal is to connect to the host using local forwarding. The command below is an example using drop bear ssh client to connect to host with local forwarding.

```
dbclient -N -i /opt/private-key-rsa.dropbear -L 2002:1.2.3.4:2006 -p 2002 -l
test_user 11.22.33.44
```

I have this code so far which returns empty connection

```
ip = "11.22.33.44"
user = "test_user"
port = 2002

ssh_config = [
  user_interaction: false,
  silently_accept_hosts: true,
  user: String.to_charlist(user),
  user_dir: String.to_charlist("/opt/")
]
# returns aunthentication error
{:ok, conn} = :ssh.connect(String.to_charlist(ip), port, ssh_config)
```

This is the error Im seeing

```
Server: 'SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.2'
Disconnects with code = 14 [RFC4253 11.1]: Unable to connect using the available authentication methods
State = {userauth,client}
Module = ssh_connection_handler, Line = 893.
Details:
  User auth failed for: "test_user"
```

I'm a newbie to elixir and have been reading this [erlang ssh](http://erlang.org/doc/man/ssh.html#connect-3) document for 2 days. I did not find any examples in the documentation which makes it difficult to understand.

Comment: Does your example command work from the shell?

Comment: @NicNilov Yes it does work

Answer (score 2):

You are using non-default key name, `private-key-rsa.dropbear`. Erlang by default looks for this set of names:

> From [ssh module docs](http://erlang.org/doc/man/ssh.html#type-key_cb_common_option):
>
> - Optional: one or more User's private key(s) in case of publickey authorization. The default files are
>
>   - id_dsa and id_dsa.pub
>   - id_rsa and id_rsa.pub
>   - id_ecdsa and id_ecdsa.pub`

To verify this is a reason, try renaming `private-key-rsa.dropbear` to `id_rsa`. If this works, the next step would be to add a [`key_cb` callback](http://erlang.org/doc/man/ssh.html#type-key_cb_common_option) to the `ssh_config` which should return the correct key file name.

One example implementation of a similar feature is [labzero/ssh_client_key_api](https://github.com/labzero/ssh_client_key_api/blob/master/lib/ssh_client_key_api.ex).

Comment: You're right. Also, the keys from dropbear (dbclient) are not compatible with ssh keys. I had to convert dropbear key to ssh key. See answer for more details.

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to convert dropbear key to ssh key. I have used [this link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134096/are-dropbear-and-openssh-host-keys-compatible) as reference.

Here is the command to convert dropbear key to ssh key

```
/usr/lib/dropbear/dropbearconvert dropbear openssh /opt/private-key-rsa.dropbear /opt/id_rsa
```